# MaskedExtender and CalendarExtender in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one textbox in asp.net application. I have used MaskedEditExtender and CalendarExtender. I use the date format yyyy-mm-dd. When i type the date in textbox the typed date displayed in the textbox. But when i select date from calender the date is not displayed in the textbox. Only the masked format "**_*-***-_" is displayed. Can anyone able to help me to solve the problem. Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your CalendarExtender has the `runat="server"`, `Format="yyyy-mm-dd"` and `TargetControlID="YourTextBox"` properties set.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using JQuery? It has a lovely Calendar control (datePicker) which is part of the JQuery.UI library. Much more useful than the ASP.AjaxToolkit stuff!